# How to TextToSpeech.getDefaultLanguage() in API level 8?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-2.2-froyo

In one of my apps, I need to determine the default language that's set for the default TTS engine.

Setting this *"TTS engine's default language"* is usually set by the user, touching the settings icon on the right-hand side of the TTS engine (e.g. SVOX Classic TTS, Google Text-to-speech, etc.), then selecting `Language`)

Unfortunately, the ability to get this information directly was only introduced in API 18, via [TextToSpeech.getDefaultLanguage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getDefaultLanguage%28%29).

Is there a way (albeit longer) to achieve the same in API 8 (Android 2.2)?

Note: I did try calling [TextToSpeech.getLanguage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getLanguage%28%29) but all it returns is the currently **used** language, not necessarily the default set one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in onInit(int status) you call getLanguage() before calling setLanguage(Locale loc) you will get the default set by the user. I tested in my phone setting Italian to be the default using the system settings and when call getLanguage the locale return is Italian. When I change it to German again I got the return locale to be Deutch.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I call getLanguage() before calling setLanguage(Locale loc), it [sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18477656/562776) returns null. Ever seen this before?

Comment: Did you call in onInit?

Comment: Absolutely. I actually call it twice: The first time, it returns null. The second time it returns eng_USA, despite the fact that settings show clearly eng_GBR is set. Why is this happening? Thanks +1.

Comment: As stated in the answer, I got the correct return when I called getLanguage in onInit. My default locale is USA, so I do not know why you got the incorrect return. May be you should post your code.