# Why would TextToSpeech.getLanguage() *sometimes* return null?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my app, I call [TextToSpeech.getLanguage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getLanguage%28%29) well after instantiating TextToSpeech (~800ms according to LogCat), yet it **sometimes** (not always) return null, despite the language set properly in the system's TextToSpeech settings:

```
System Settings > Language & input > 
  Text-to-speech output > Google Text-to-speech > English (United Kingdom)
```

This only happens in Jelly Bean (Android **4.1.1**).
It doesn't happen in Android 2.2.

Is this a known Android bug?
Or am I doing something wrong?

I instantiate, BTW, TextToSpeech in my app's main activity with:

```
new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

And both instantiation and the call to  [TextToSpeech.getLanguage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getLanguage%28%29) are made in the same thread (thus order of calls is guaranteed).

Answer (score 2):

You have to call getLanguage () in onInit (), sometimes it takes a few second for onInit () to be called.

Comment: Or any time after the callback indicates that the TTS service has finished initializing.

Comment: @alanv you are absolutely right, he need to set a flag to true in onInit () and check if this flag is true before calling getLanguage ()

Comment: @alanv I actually call it twice in onInit(): The first time, it returns null. The second time it returns eng_USA, despite the fact that settings show clearly eng_GBR is set. Again, *sometimes* it does return eng_GBR correctly in the first & second calls. Looks like some kind of race condition? **Why** is this happening? What could possibly explains this?

Answer (score 1):

I also discovered this bug today on an Asus TF700T running Android 4.1.1.  I tried to resolve the issue by calling `getLanguage()` again as Eternal Learner suggested in a comment, but it still returns null no matter how many times I call it.

The easiest workaround for me was to abandon the current broken instance of TextToSpeech and create a new instance.  The second instance seems to work reliably.